# Mac OS X 10.8 - Configure smbd to follow symbolic links

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

Is there a way to change the configuration for smbd in mountain lion to follow symbolic links?

I was looking to apply this fix for linux: http://littlehandytips.com/samba-symbolic-links-do-not-work/

> To fix the samba problem with accessing symbolic links, you will need
>   to modify the samba config file, smb.conf which is normally at
>   /etc/samba/smb.conf and add the following lines to the [global]
>   section in that file.
>
> follow symlinks = yes
>
> wide links = yes
>
> unix extensions = no

But I can't seem to find the configuration file for smbd.

Looking at the man pages for smbd in OS X lion 
https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/smbd.8.html

> -no-symlinks
>
> ```
>           In normal operation, smbd will respond to client symlink requests but will never follow sym-links symlinks
>           links itself. This flag causes smbd to restrict client access to symlink operations and to
>           always follow symlinks. In this case, clients will not be aware that symlinks are in use
>           because they will always be directed to the symlink target.
> ```

I tried adding 'no-symlinks' as a program argument in smbd's launchdaemon plist, but no success.

**Update: solved
Adding the -no-symlinks parameter to the plist did fix the issue, the file sharing services just needed a restart after that.

/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist

```
<array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/smbd</string>
        <string>-no-symlinks</string>  
</array>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `no-symlinks` as a program argument in smbd's launchdaemon plist did the trick.

The file sharing services do need a restart after changing the file.

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist

<array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/smbd</string>
        <string>-no-symlinks</string>  
</array>
```

Comment: It's Bad to change a file in `/System`. It might be overwritten at system update

Comment: This is a bit weird. Reading the `smbd --help` would suggest that `-no-symlinks (disable support for symbolic links)` removes support for them entirely, which indeed is the case in Finder when mounted. They're simply not listed. I cannot even `Cmd+G` my way to a symlinked folder. In Terminal, however, they're all there, and functional — resolved similar to how "wide links" and friends work on a Linux server share. Have you had any success in getting Finder to show these symlinked resources? Cheers :)